# The difference beteween Nokogiri::HTML(open(url).read) and Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))?

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri, open-uri

I am working with Nokogiri for one of the first times and searching through HTML documents.  When I create a variable(and print) that is equal to:

```
beteween Nokogiri::HTML(open(url).read)
```

it seems to output the same exact thing as

```
beteween Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
```

Is there a difference?

I could not find an answer in documentation and tried to see if I could figure out the difference, but am having trouble.

Answer (score 7):

Pretty new to Nokogiri here, too, but have some experience with it. As far as Nokogiri is concerned, it handles both of your examples the same way. However, `open(url)` and `open(url).read` are different — the former returns a `Tempfile` object while the latter returns a `String` object.

Nokogiri is all about making your life easier for you, though. "[You don’t need to read the file into a string variable. Nokogiri will do this for you.](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html)" So, save yourself a few keystrokes and go with `Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))`.